# ImportError: cannot import name GoogleCredentials

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use `GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()`:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from ferris.core.google_api_helper import build

...

gcs = build("storage", "v1", GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())
response = gcs.objectAccessControls.insert(bucket=bucket,
                                           object=filename,
                                           body={"entity": "user-<email>",
                                                 "role": "READER", }).execute()
logging.info(response)
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx", line 2, in <module>
    from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
ImportError: cannot import name GoogleCredentials
```

This happens in the development and production environments. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you import a higher level of the module? eg `client` or `oauth2client`?

Comment: I tried `import oauth2client.client`, and then `oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()`, which removes the import error but give me `'module' object has no attribute 'GoogleCredentials'`.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling it right? Can you look into the file where the module is and see if you can find `GoogleCredentials`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below my code to insert credentials

```
import json
from oauth2client import appengine
from apiclient import discovery
import httplib2
import logging


SCOPE_FULL_CONTROL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'

http = httplib2.Http()
credentials = appengine.AppAssertionCredentials(scope=SCOPE_FULL_CONTROL)
http = credentials.authorize(http)
client = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', http=http)


def api_insert_gcs_user_acl(bucket, bucket_object, e_mail):

    # Cloud Storage API : https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/python/latest/
    req = client.objectAccessControls().insert(
        bucket=bucket,
        object=bucket_object,
        body=dict(entity='user-' + e_mail, role='READER')
    )

    resp = req.execute()
    logging.info(json.dumps(resp, indent=2))
```

The appengine Google Cloud Storage Client Library does not support setting or deleting ACL entries. But the SDK can use the REST API and a service account to access the hosted Cloud storage.
An appengine service accounts makes it very easy to use OAuth2 and Python APIs.
To make this work in the SDK, you have to use two options in development server:

```
--appidentity_email_address=<developer service account e-mail address>
--appidentity_private_key_path=<d:/.../gcs-blobstore.pem key>
```

Comment: oauth2client is deprecated
https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/oauth2client-deprecation.html

Answer (score 2):

Solution: 
1. **uninstalled all google-python tools**
    pip uninstall googledatastore
    pip uninstall google-api-python-client

from add/remove programs, uninstalled google app engine launcher

2. Delete the left over files from all installations from program files and other places.
3. Re-install google python tools
   pip install google-api-python-client

now the error disappeared!

Comment: Yes, uninstalling `oauth2client` and then reinstalling `google-api-python-client` worked for me.  When you install `google-api-python-client`, it will automatically install the correct "oauth2client" for you.